# I'm trying to create a put request and delete request with a complicated array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, request

I'm trying to create a put request and delete but I don't know how to do with the DUMMY-PLACES.I will get at the beginning (id, content) and the completed by default is false (it's a dummy DB ) for example (6,test6) of course that's the number in byIds need to be the same"6"

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    todos: {
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      byIds: {
        "1": {
          content: "test1",
          completed: false,
        },
        "2": {
          content: "test2",
          completed: false,
        },
        "3": {
          content: "test3\\",
          completed: false,
        },
        "4": {
          content: "test4",
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    },
    visibilityFilter: "all",
  },
];

router.get("/todos", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const place = DUMMY_PLACES;
    console.log(place);
    res.json({ place });
  } catch (err) {
    next({ status: 400, message: "failed to get todos" });
  }
  // => { place } => { place: place }
});

router.put("/todos/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, content } = req.body;
  try {
    todo = DUMMY_PLACES;
    console.log(todo.todos);
  } catch (err) {
    next({ status: 400, message: "failed to update todo" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a single todo, first check if it actually exists and update it according.

```
router.put("/todos", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, content } = req.body;
  // Check if todo actually exists
  const todoExists = DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds.hasOwnProperty(id);
  if (!todoExists) {
    next({ status: 400, message: `todo with id ${id} does not exist` });
  }
  // Update todo
  DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds[id].content = content;
  res.sendStatus(200);  
});
```

To remove a todo, delete the key from the byIds object

```
router.put("/todos", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  delete DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds[id];
  res.sendStatus(200);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very helped me to map it. very good response.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can add a new todo in the byIds?

Comment: @Ethanolle add a POST route and add the new todo to the byIds object